# Export ListView to CSV

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, csv

Is anyone aware of a decent CSV export tool for exporting from a ListView? I need to get a project update out and feature creep means I don't have time to get this final feature implemented myself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's not a big feature I'd say, unless you have some very odd requirements... but in this case, probably, no external tool can help you anyway.

Here is how I would approach the problem:

```
class ListViewToCSV
{
    public static void ListViewToCSV(ListView listView, string filePath, bool includeHidden)
    {
        //make header string
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listView.Columns[i].Text);

        //export data rows
        foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
            WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listItem.SubItems[i].Text);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, result.ToString());
    }

    private static void WriteCSVRow(StringBuilder result, int itemsCount, Func<int, bool> isColumnNeeded, Func<int, string> columnValue)
    {
        bool isFirstTime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            if (!isColumnNeeded(i))
                continue;

            if (!isFirstTime)
                result.Append(",");
            isFirstTime = false;

            result.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", columnValue(i)));
        }
        result.AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. One issue I've just found is that if the first column of your listview is an uppercase "ID", then excel refuses to open the CSV file without generating an error, as it stupidly thinks the file is an SYLK file. The best workaround I've found to prevent this happening is to simply convert the headers to lowercase. MS state you can put an apostrophe as the first character on the first line to fix this, but then you get an ugly apostrophe show up in excel. More info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215591

Comment: @Yacoder what about .net 3.5 most of these properties aren't available there

Comment: @ShehabFawzy What do you mean? Which properties? I think this was written for .NET 3.5, maybe even before.

Comment: @Yacoder listView.Columns and all it's methods aren't available in 3.5

Comment: @ShehabFawzy: We're talking about WinForms here, should be available, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columns(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Yacoder I though you were talking about asp.net :( sorry my mistake, but do you have any hints or advice on how to use it with asp.net ?

Comment: @ShehabFawzy: I'm not sure about ASP.NET, you can ask a new question on SO with your problem.

Comment: @jyelton WOW thanks, saved me so much trouble. only one small change though in .net 4 you have to cast `listItem.SubItems[i].Text` as `((ListViewItem)listItem).SubItems[i].Text`

Comment: This works well but is difficult to modify for those of us that aren't familiar with lambda expressions. It'd be nice if someone could post a less 'shorthand' version of the code

Answer (score 2):

[FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) is a nice library that might just be your best friend today