# need help passing list to this csv export class

Tags: c#, export, export-to-csv

I found this CSV export class online and would like to pass my own list from another class
my list is already prepared and contains 3 columns

```
 using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Data.SqlTypes;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Reflection;


          public class CsvExport<T> where T : class
        {
            public List<T> Objects;

            public CsvExport(List<T> objects)
            {
                Objects = objects;
            }

            public string Export()
            {
                return Export(true);
            }

            public string Export(bool includeHeaderLine)
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //Get properties using reflection.
                IList<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();

                if (includeHeaderLine)
                {
                    //add header line.
                    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                    {
                        sb.Append(propertyInfo.Name).Append(",");
                    }
                    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
                }

                //add value for each property.
                foreach (T obj in Objects)
                {
                    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                    {
                        sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null))).Append(",");
                    }
                    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).AppendLine();
                }

                return sb.ToString();
            }

            //export to a file.
            public void ExportToFile(string path)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
            }

            //export as binary data.
            public byte[] ExportToBytes()
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Export());
            }

            //get the csv value for field.
            private string MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value)
            {
                if (value == null) return "";
                if (value is Nullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) return "";

                if (value is DateTime)
                {
                    if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == 0)
                        return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                }
                string output = value.ToString();

                if (output.Contains(",") || output.Contains("\""))
                    output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';

                return output;

            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your question???

Comment: So what is your question? How to use the class? or how to set up your class to work with it?  Exporting CSV is really quite simple, I would very much prefer to write my own class to handle it which

Comment: well my list isnt called list<t>, should i change it to my actuall list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want help using the class then I would say you need to do something like this.

Create a class for your data..

```
public class MyData
{
   public string Column1Data {get;set;}
   public string Column2Data {get;set;}
   public string Column3Data {get;set;}
}
```

the pass a List of type MyData into your CsvExport class like this...

```
List<MyData> list = new List<MyData>();
//populate the list here
CsvExport<MyData> export = new CsvExport<MyData>();
export.ExportToFile(@"C:\MyExportFile.txt");
```

you should now have an output file like...

```
Column1Data,Column2Data,Column3Data 
r1c1,r1c2,r1c3
r2c1,r2c2,r2c3
r3c1,r1c2,r3c3
```

To use a different input class just switch MyData references to what ever you class is called

Comment: what if i wanted to export a result from another class

Comment: @bugz: the CsvExport class you are using uses reflection to create column values based on the properties. Therefor the class you pass it needs to have only properties that you want in your export. In my opinion this is not a good method to go by anyway. What data does your input class have? How are you storing column header and data?

Comment: the class returns the exact data i need
 return result.Where(i => IForEmployee(facade, i.Employee)).ToList();

Is what it returns and it includes
Employee = employee,
Manager = manager,
Weeks = new List<string> { new Week(info.Week).ToString("end") }

result is the list i need  var result = new List<Approve>();

Comment: @bugz: can you post the structure of your class please (in a seperate code block - so it has its on scroll)

Comment: ahh i think its working, problem is the program takes forever to run

Comment: @bugs: that could be down to the use of reflection in the CsvExport class. I would suggest you write your own method that lets you specify the columns and lets you pass a list of rows. There are loads of examples for this around. check this answer for example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008556/c-sharp-export-listview-to-csv

Answer (score 3):

Here is sample of using Exporter with sample class

```
class Sample
{
   public string Field1 {get;set;}
   public int Field2 {get;set;}
}

List<Sample> source = new List<Sample>()

// fill list 

CsvExport<Sample> export = new CsvExport<Sample>(source);
export.ExportToFile("yourFile.csv");
```

So basically create `CsvExport<YourClass>` and path list of existing objects to it