# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - *.csv file opening

Tags: c#, excel

I create `*.csv` file, but when I open it using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, it's formatting is wrong, because of ignoring the delimiter `;`.

```
excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0,
                    false,5,"","", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true,
                    false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Which parameter of `Workbooks.Open` should I change?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter argument, which is the 9th one. Change `""` to `";"`.
For more info, check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be:

```
excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0,
                false,5,"","", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, ";", true,
                false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Interop Excel has a format to open CSV files.

```
excel_app.Workbooks.Open(
        txtFile.Text,               // Filename
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV,   // Format
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        txtDelimiter.Text,          // Delimiter
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing,
        Type.Missing);
```

Format and Delimiter combo should be working in all cases.

[Source](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/08/load-a-csv-file-in-excel-in-c/)