# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - opening csv with semicolon delimiter

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have read [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - *.csv file opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325936/microsoft-office-interop-excel-csv-file-opening) but it does not work for me and I don't know why.

First I tried only using the optional parameters I need like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, Delimiter:";");
```

It opens the csv but separates at the comma.

Then I tried like in the referenced thread above and it does not separate at all.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path,0,false,5, "","",false,Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,";",true,false,0,true,false,false);
```

Here is some sample data I used:

```
2,138;2,066;2,022;2,076;0,297;;;0,770;1,898;1,864;1,798;1,859;1,715;20,032;8,599;0,039;;;0,336;Iteration: 5 of 500
0,298;0,295;0,298;0,297;0,297;;;0,302;0,296;0,296;0,297;0,297;0,299;0,300;0,296;0,037;;;0,409;Iteration: 6 of 500
0,297;0,299;0,296;0,297;0,311;;;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,295;0,306;0,306;0,039;;;0,372;Iteration: 7 of 500
0,299;0,298;0,295;0,297;0,295;;;0,294;0,307;0,295;0,295;0,296;0,297;0,296;0,295;0,040;;;0,368;Iteration: 8 of 500
```

Has anyone an idea what im doing wrong?

When I open the csv file with a double click (excel standard program to open csv) it formats it as I want. With the semicolon as delimiter. I probably have set it in the properties once.

Comment: can you save the .csv also as .txt? I had a similar problem once and changing .csv to .txt and then using Workbooks.OpenText fixed it, I honestly don't know exactly why though...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it. But I still think this is strange because I set the delimiter and it does not accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `OpenText`:

```
Excel.Application ex = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbooks wbs = ex.Workbooks;

wbs.OpenText(path,
    DataType:Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, 
    Semicolon: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia

Format  Object

Optional Object. If Microsoft Excel is opening a text file, this argument specifies the delimiter character, as shown in the following table. **If this argument is omitted, the current delimiter is used.**

...

Delimiter Object

Optional Object. **If the file is a text file and the Format argument is 6,** this argument is a string that specifies the character to be used as the delimiter. For example, use Chr(9) for tabs, use "," for commas, use ";" for semicolons, or use a custom character. Only the first character of the string is used.

So your open statement should be:
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, Format:6, Delimiter:";");